# wrapInner doesn't add children to wrapping element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to do an innerWrap, then manipulate the contents of the wrap.  However, the wrap never seems to get it's children added!  Here's a test, showing the issue:

```
var images = $(element).find('img');
console.log(images);
var wrap = document.createElement("div")
$(element).wrapInner(wrap)
var images2 = $(wrap).find('img');
console.log(images2);
```

**[View as JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ycur1y/)**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when you pass an element to `.wrapInner()` function, a structurally identical copy of that element, and not the element itself is wrapped around the contents. In your example, you will notice the following:

- The `#element` ends up having one child as expected: a div that contains three images
- But `wrap.parentNode` is `null` indicating that it is present in memory, not attached to DOM
- And `wrap ===  $("#element").children().get(0)` returns false confirming the assumption

Solution: revise your code like this:

```
var $images1 = $("#element").find('img');
$("#element").wrapInner("<div></div>");
var $images2 = $("#element").children().find("img");
// the div can be accessed by doing $("#element").children()
console.log($images1.length, $images2.length, $images1.get(0) === $images2.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks... ugh, that's a really annoying 'feature' that i wish the jQuery documentation covered.  I have a new working fiddle, thanks to you: http://jsfiddle.net/n8c7fnrb/1/

Comment: This "feature" actually makes sense, since it is not possible to use the same element to act as a wrapper for contents of multiple elements (see [hello cruel world example here](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)).